# If we numerically code the categories of an ordinal variable, then can we determine its mean as in Likert scale?

Tags: mean, ordinal-data, likert, bimodal, central-tendency

Can anyone clear my doubts about 2 things.

Doubt1)A dataset of Ordinal type having 2 modes, then does it mean that such dataset have 2 central locations ?

Doubt2)As We know that we can not determine Mean of Ordinal data.But if we numerically code the categories of Ordinal variable, then Can we determine its Mean as in Likert scale ?If so then the Mean so obtained can be trusted ?

Comment: I've edited your post to give it a more informative title. Feel free to revise it, but please note that a title describing the question content is essential.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between levels of an ordinal variable is often indeterminate or disproportionate. Thus, the difference or sum of ordinal observations is ill-defined without further validation. For example, consider a 5-point Likert scale. Obviously, a score of 2 = 'somewhat disagree' is greater than a score of 1 = 'strongly disagree,' but by how much? Is this the same as the distance between a score 5 = 'strongly agree' and 4 = 'somewhat agree'? Additionally, the labels assigned to levels of an ordinal variable are completely arbitrary and changing the labels will change the value of the mean. As a result, the mean is not a meaningful summary measure. With two groups, the Mann-Whitney probability can be used to quantify differences without the need to calculate distances (i.e. based on ranks alone). With one group, the median is typically the summary measure used.